Where on the surface of the Earth would be best to start a colony from scratch?
I have been tasked by my College Writing professor to write an essay my choice of real people from my personal life to recolonize the Earth. I am looking for inspiration as to where this would take place. This is a summary of the prompt:

The President of the U.S.A. has chosen you and 9 others to colonize for the survival of humanity. They are normal, everyday people, no celebrities or survival gurus. The identity of the President is not an important plot point.

Only allowed natural resources provided by the land; no tools, seeds, animals, etc. Only the clothes off your back, glasses if you need them.

No-one is alive anywhere else. There are no bunkers to stay in, nor any abandoned buildings or stores to raid.

You must reproduce to save humanity, so children must be able to survive as well


Any ideas as for what would wipe out society in such a manner and suggestions in general are also welcome.

Are these people supposed to have received extensive training on how to survive and develop advanced Stone Age technology? Because otherwise I'm afraid that the story will be very short and end tragically.

AlexP - This is a very good point that I will have to include. Individuals are to be chosen based on essential skills. For instance, we will need people who are physically capable of building structures as well as designing them to be safe and hopefully long-lasting. There should be individuals that could be able to hunt well, someone to make tools for the hunters, etc. Survival of humanity is at stake, but theses are the only humans alive.

My point is that extremely few modern people know how to make Stone Age tools and implements, and how to use them. Its not a question of body strength, it is a question of knowledge and training. To cut a tree they need to know how to identify the correct kind of stone to make a stone axe, and how to make an axe head, and how to attach the stone axe head to a wooden handle, and how to use the stone axe. And how to make needles out of fish bones, and how to extract fibres from whatever they extracted fibers in the Stone Age, and how to make thread and ten thousand other such things.

Since the only way to set up the scenario is magic (to get rid of all the people and ruins and farmland and so on) and complete rejection of basic internal consistency (the president of WHAT UNITED STATES?), I recommend making the 9 other people wizards and conjuring everything you want out of thin air. The ideal place is obviously the mystical crystal formation that powers the wizardry.

"To cut a tree they need to know how to identify the correct kind of stone to make a stone axe, and how to make an axe head, and how to attach the stone axe head to a wooden handle, and how to use the stone axe" that sounds like an awful lot of work @AlexP ..  so I think I'm going to choose somewhere with a nice pleasant climate (like the south of France perhaps) and plentiful rainfall that also just happens to have a plentiful beaver population, I'm going to steal my logs from them  anyone know somewhere like that?

wiping out humanity so thoroughly there is no metal lying around but any humans can survive, thats basically impossible.

It's kind of hard to answer 'where' to start afresh without knowing the 'what' as in what killed everybody off. because that will have an impact on the where e.g. nuclear war, plague, asteroid impact??? Each could lead to a different decision about where to start a colony.

I’m voting to close this question because (a) We don't do people's homework for them, (b) This specific question (where'd the best location for X?) is regularly closed unless there's a lengthy list of requirements, otherwise there's too many options all with pros and cons leading to the prohibited answers all having equal value, making the question too opinion-based. Honestly, your class project is likely trying to teach you how to think a problem through. You shouldn't let others do it for you.

Voted close. ChatGPT will help you cheat on your homework, we won’t

The answer entirely depends on an exhaustive list of criteria, including but not limited to the exact details of what happened to the rest of the population and world, a subject upon which you also want our input, this is your story, we don't do plot.

I totally missed the part of this question where it was assigned as homework - oops!

@AlexP Stone tools are not a prerequisite to survival, many people never had much need for stone tools. People can and do cut up pigs with bamboo and shell implements. You have a very limited and ethnocentric view of how pre metal societies handled things.

@Kilisi: The vast majority of tools in the Stone Age and in the Bronze Age and in the Iron Age and even up to the dawn of the Industrial Revolution were made of wood. The problem is in those situation when you need something better than wood, for example, to cut a tree in order to make those wooden tools, or a house or a boat.

@AlexP people can and do build houses, cut down trees and make dugouts without metal or stone. You have an ethnocentric viewpoint, best not to project it to cultures and techs you don't understand. We don't have suitable stone here, but my ancestors built huge seagoing craft, buildings and lived & flourished without it. Imported knapped stone tools in prehistory were luxury and status items, not necessities.

@gs The survivors could have been transported by 'science accident' to an alternate version of earth where humanity never developed. Which would make the question more interesting, as you would have to take into account only the resources that 'spawned' there, and weren't imported by people at some point in time.

Tropical Central Pacific Island would be best.
Food is easy to get from the sea and land with minimal effort. There are no dangerous predators or poisonous animals in most of them. The climate is tropical, you can stroll around naked if you want. Water isn't a problem.
Your biggest problem is that 10 people are not enough to repopulate, inbreeding will soon become a serious issue. They can survive just fine and have a bunch of kids though.

Thank you. This is a College writing prompt that seems to be designed to have writers choose individuals from their personal lives. It makes no sense in terms of inbreeding, however that is what the professor requires.

The answer would be very much more useful if it included an actual description of how the colonists could survive on such an island. What is there to eat? Do these islands have stone suitable for making tools? I for one know very little of Hawaii, Tahiti and Samoa. (Are there any non-tiny islands other than Hawaii, Tahiti and Samoa?)

@AlexP Tahiti, Hawaii and Samoa are not islands, they're countries. Out of those, only Samoa is Central Polynesia. If you don't know anything about them, you could look them up?

England or New Zealand
Not too hot, not too cold, plenty of Water, Plenty of resources, very little natural predators, lots of game animals, very fertile soil for growing crops.
The list goes on.
I would say that England probably is the better choice, because assuming the Colony gets up and running (which given the number of survivors is a virtually nil probability - but hey - your world, your rules) - you can then easily expand into Europe.
Whereas in NZ, it's a long trip to anywhere.

That's a shame, NZ is gorgeous  well, not all of it maybe, but certainly some pretty significant chunks of it.

Lets think about what you need
food, water, timber, metal, clay.
Some good stone is a bonus but you should be transitionsing to iron tools as fast as possible. If they are repopulating proximity to large structures can be helpful for sources of metal. some humans structures will be around for thousands of years at least as sources of metal.
The eastern US is prime for much of that, lots of still standing timberland, lots of rivers and streams. Fairly easy access to ground water for good drinking water longterm. Thanks ot extensive farming surviving crops and livestock should be common enough to re-domesticate. lots of fruit trees thanks to fruit farming. lots of fish, shelfish and hunting for food until then. If you go just a little into the future so blight resistant american chestnut AKA the bread tree has been reestablished even better.
you do have a compromise to make, mainland means predators, but islands make you vunerable to weather and shortages and growth limits. which you choose is up to you, but I would say mainland. You can't just pick up and move on an island. also it is possible most large islands will not be free of predators thanks to feral dogs. warm is better at first, esspecially until you have built metal tools. But as your population grows you want to be able to move north to escape epidemics from mosquitos and ticks.
